# Is there a better way to apply theme with CSS modules in React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-modules

I'm using CSS modules as a styling solution in my React application, and I have a dark and a light theme. Currently, I use this approach to style a component based on the current theme:

```
  import styles from './NominationsList.module.scss'
  //......
  <p
    className={`${styles.nominationsHeader} ${
      isDarkMode ? styles.nominationsHeaderDark : styles.nominationsHeaderLight
    }`}
  >
   Some text here...
  </p>
```

Even though it works, there has to be a better way to do so. I'd appreciate any advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A number of libraries, such as MaterialUI provide mechanisms for managing themes, but if you're not utilizing any of them I'd recommend you check out the useTheme hook at https://usehooks.com/useTheme/.

Basically, you'd define a dark mode them and a light mode theme once, specify the current one with useTheme() and then reference the theme classes as necessary without any additional conditional logic.

Comment: Not OP but does useTheme support changing classes for themes? For people who use Bootstrap, Tailwind, etc. it might be better than allowing changing css.

Comment: that's an interesting approach. Thanks.

Comment: `useTheme` is not found on usehooks.com or github

Answer (score 0):

I love [this](https://electricanimals.com/articles/next-js-dark-mode-toggle) approach because it also allows for consideration of the user's scheme preference. It makes use of variables and attributes that will solve the issue of those conditional classes.

Comment: Answers should provide enough info by itself. External links can easily go stale and make this answer useless. Please edit to include a summary of the external link and enough code to demonstrate the method.